# Binary Search Tree using std::unique ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm trying to implement a Binary Search Tree using smart pointers and I've read that the recommended way to implement it is by using unique_ptr since a parent owns the child and there are no multiple owners in a binary search tree.

Take this tree for example,

```
                       10
            4                      20       
      2           5          11          30
         3
```

here 4 is left child of 10 and 2 is left child of 4 and 3 is right child of 2 and so on.

Now the struct looks like,

```
template<typename T>
struct TreeNode {
    T data;
    std::unique_ptr<TreeNode<T>> left, right; 
};
```

there's a `unique_ptr<TreeNode<T>> root` pointing to the root.

Now if I'm understanding it correctly `unique_ptr's` can't be copied or assigned and they have unique ownership of the object.

So if I want to traverse the tree I can't do something like initialize a `std::unique_ptr<TreeNode<T>> temp` to the root and traverse every node from there since it'll throw an error once I try to set the `root` which is a `unique_ptr` to the `temp`.

So do I need to use a raw pointer of type `TreeNode*` to traverse the tree and perform operations? is it good or safe to do so? For all my operations on this tree then will I have to use raw pointers?

Another problem is with deleting a node. If I say want to delete node with the value `3`. If I initialize a raw pointer of type `TreeNode* temp` and arrive at `Treenode 3`. Then if I call delete(temp) what will happen? A `unique_ptr` from `TreeNode 2` is pointing at `TreeNode 3`. What will happen to this pointer?

Comment: *if I call `delete(temp)` what will happen* - undefined behaviour.

Comment: `TreeNode*` can be used to traverse the tree (as long as you don't use that pointer for its owner ship (transfer or delete)).

Comment: @Evg only if the `unique_ptr` holding it is accessed or destroyed

Comment: Nothing wrong with using raw pointers, the smart pointers take care of the ownership, if you only use smart pointers for ownership then its clear in your code that any raw pointer doesn't own the pointed to object

Comment: *"If I say want to delete node"* You should only need code like `left = nullptr;`, `root = nullptr;` to remove the node (and its children). No `delete` to write. code like `root = std::move(root->left);` might be useful too.

Comment: You are asking multiple questions about smart pointers. One focused question per Stackoverflow question, please?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So it's safe to use raw pointers to traverse. For delete I'm thinking of going for a method like say to delete `TreeNode 3`, I arrive at it's parent, in this case `TreeNode 2` and use `reset()` on the `unique_ptr` like `Parent->right.reset()`. Will this be good for delete operation?

Comment: It would be best if just start implementing stuff and post new question when something doesn't work. Then your question(s) will be focused on specific problem and will provide code which we can fix/improve.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I was having trouble about going how to implement it so I posted this question. From next time I'll first implement and then post the exact same error or question that I have. I

Comment: TBH I find smart pointers can sometimes be of limited value when creating data structures at such a low level. I think they can add more complication than they are worth. For example, you could create every `TreeNode` as if it was itself a "smart pointer" bearing in mind the rule of `5`.

Comment: @Galik Then you have to deal with things like `right = new TreeNode` throwing, to correctly clean up `left`. Much easier to delegate that to somewhere else.

Comment: @Caleth Yes, but you can often use temporary smart pointers to achieve exception safety. I am not saying in every case, smart pointers aren't worth it. Just that I don't think you should take it for granted they will be more useful than not when constructing data structures at low level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then if I call delete(temp) what will happen?

The `TreeNode` will be destroyed. Note that `delete` doesn't need parentheses

> A `unique_ptr` from `TreeNode` 2 is pointing at `TreeNode` 3. What will happen to this pointer?

The pointer becomes invalid, and it is undefined behaviour for the `unique_ptr` object to be destroyed, as it will attempt to `delete` an invalid pointer.

> So do I need to use a raw pointer of type TreeNode* to traverse the tree and perform operations? is it good or safe to do so? For all my operations on this tree then will I have to use raw pointers?

You can have a reference (or pointer) to a `std::unique_ptr`, you don't need to copy it.

Rather than `delete` a raw pointer, you can call the `reset` member function of the `unique_ptr` to free the pointed-to `TreeNode`